# Coins changing algorithm problem - not working

Tags: javascript, algorithm, coin-change

I'm using the following algorithm for coins changing problem:

```
for (let coin of coins){
    if(change >= coin){
        if (Math.floor(change/coin) > 0){
            console.log(Math.floor(change/coin)+ " pièces de " + coin + " euro");
            let newChange = change - coin;
            change = newChange;
        }
    }
 }
```

The result should look like below:

```
Purchase of €1.34 paid for with €5:
Change: €3.66 
Coins returned:
2 euro: 1 
1 euro: 1
50 cents: 1 
10 cents: 1 
5 cents: 1 
1 cent: 1
```

My results look like this:

```
Purchase of $1.34 paid for with $5
Change: 3.66
1 pièces de 2 euro
1 pièces de 1 euro
1 pièces de 0.5 euro
1 pièces de 0.1 euro
1 pièces de 0.05 euro
1 pièces de 0.01 euro
```

Comment: The assign of `newChange` is wrong and should be `change = change % coin` (as modulo)

Comment: Ok yes :) thank you :) It is working!

Comment: Glad to help. To make it easier for other user I added formal answer - if it helped you you may mark it as accepted (the grey "v" mark at the left of the post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that your line: `let newChange = change - coin;` is wrong as it assume only 1 coin has been given and ignore case of multi coins.

New assignment to change var should be the modulo of the change after reduce the coin so change your if to:

```
if (Math.floor(change/coin) > 0){
    console.log(Math.floor(change/coin)+ " pièces de " + coin + " euro");
    change  = change % coin;
}
```